# Smart Contract (Solidity) Auction when bidders abstracted from their wallets

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I have a web site which sells certain information for its users for a fixed cost.
I want to go ICO with my business and trying to change my operating model so it can leverage blockchain technology.

However I want to make sure that auction participants are in some way abstracted from their Ethereum wallet and budding in points (they will pay later if action is actually won. i.e. eBay model) without knowing that they are actually using blockchain behind the scenes. Once bidding is complete, ICO investors will automatically get their share distributed to them, and winning bidder will receive their info upon payment (in most cases real money which we will convert to ETH and mark status as paid in solidity contract)

Is there any solution for that problem, can i create wallets on the fly for the bidders accounts? Since my site is always a seller, is there a way to set auctions automatically (interact with my contract from my lets say java backed etc?)
Is there any work around/ suggestions?
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can create wallets on the fly for your customers. That's perfectly doable. But as you create the wallets, customers can't trust those wallets you have their private keys, so they should withdraw the funds immediately to their wallets. This took us to step 0: Wallet creation. So either way, your customers have to create a wallet for themselves, for security reasons.